# Python package with multiple "packages"?

Tags: python, python-packaging

Assume I have a project which looks like

```
uilities.py
api_1.py
api_2.py
api_3.py
foo.py
bar.py
baz.py
```

The utilites and api calls does nothing by their own, but they form 90% of the contents of foo.py, bar.py and baz.py.

- The contents of foo.py, bar.py and baz.py. are very bare bones, including the commandline interface they are maybe 200 lines each.
- The utility.py and api_?.py does little to nothing on their own.

E.g when I call

```
foo -a --other-arg
```

Instead of doing, which is what I tried

```
long_main_package_name foo -a --other-arg
```

How should i structure my project so that I can call foo.py, bar.py and baz.py directly after installing the package?

Comment: How you structure the project is independent of the package it is supposed to produce. I agree with the recent answer: `foo`, `bar`, and `baz` aren't part of any package, but standalone scripts that *use* the package that contains the four modules `utilities`, `api_1`, `api_2`, and `api_3`.

Comment: (And to clear up a possible misconception due to Python overloading the term "package", the *distribution package* that contains your scripts and the modules is distinct from the *Python package* which you might define to contain your four modules.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can declare them as console scripts in the setup for building the package for distribution.

More details here: https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/entry_point.html